# Python Compilation in Terminal

Tags: python, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I am participating in a CodeForces competition tomorrow, and the rules say that Python is compiled with the following line (where %1 is the filename):

```
python -c "compile(open('%1').read(), '%1', 'exec')"
```

I tried to compile a test file with this line, but it does not do anything at all:

```
import sys
a = sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write(a)
```

However, the program works when I compile with `python test.py`

How can I make this test file work with the compilation line above?

EDIT: I am using terminal on a mac.

Comment: How do you specify %1 ?

Comment: `%1` is the filename to be compiled. I replaced `%1` with `test.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what is happening if you try it in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> compile(open('test.py').read(), 'read.py', 'exec')
<code object <module> at 0x10b916130, file "read.py", line 1>
```

The [compile built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) compiles the source lines into a code object.  To actually run the code object, you need to [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) it:

```
>>> codeobj = compile(open('test.py').read(), 'read.py', 'exec')
>>> exec(codeobj)
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
>>>
```

Note that there are some differences here between Python 2 and Python 3, primarily that `exec` is a statement in Py2 but a built-in function in Py3.  The above should work in either.

Comment: [Here is a link to the docs for reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=compile#compile)